# jQuery Image loads to fast for Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, loading

i made a little Page were you can change text/image on click. My Problem is that the image is loaded to fast. It should load after the TV disappeared. Maybe it helps to unterstand my problem. Just click "test 2".

Comment: Have you tried to add a delay('1000') and see if that works??

Comment: And i think you might want to provide the link to the page....

Comment: Rephrase your question with more detail. What is TV? `test2`?

Answer (score 0):

This should be just a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do it. Sorry.

Don't know how you implement your animation and the source code is hard to read. If your problem is that while the first TV moves up and before it disappears, the picture has already become the second one, I think you could just add a callback function triggered by the end of transition. Then in that callback function, switch your picture to another one.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at your source code of the page, you might want to change this line:

```
$("img.tv").attr("src", newSRC);
```

to this:

```
$("img.tv").delay('1000').attr("src", newSRC);
```

Check and see if this works.